# The variable doesn't save previous value in recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I faced next problem.

The cut version of my code is next:

```
private void insertRandomValue(){
        variants = findVariantsOfCellWithMinimumVariants();
        for (int v = 0; v < variants.size(); v++){
            if (!checkCorrectFilling()) restoreData();
            cellWithMinVar = findCellWithMinimumVariants();
            cellWithMinVar.setValue(variants.get(v));
            fillBoard();
            if (!checkFilledBoard()) insertRandomValue();
        }
        restoreData();
    }
```

**UPDATED**:
This code is part of Sudoku Solver. The method `insertRandomValue()` realizes algorithm of deep search. The method search cells with the least quantity of possible variants in cells, insert one of variants in it and invoke method of accurate search of values `fillBoard()`. If the values in cells won't repeat in rows, columns and squares than recursion applies to find another cell with the least quantity of possible variants. If the values in cells will repeat than the method invoke method `restoreData()` which clears all cells filled after invoking of `insertRandomValue()`.

The problem is that at some stage the variable `v` is `1`. After execution of `if (!checkFilledBoard()) insertRandomValue();` the variable `v` should remain `1` too, however it is `0`. Thus, the cycle is eternal and can not be finished correctly.

I searched this problem but could not find the solution because such behavior of recursive method is strange. Besides, when I applied recursive methods in past I didn't faces such problem.

I demonstrated a little part of my code for simplifying of your reading. However, if it will be necessary I will display whole code.

I would be grateful if you throw me ideas what is the reason of this problem.

Comment: The variable `v` is not an iterator.  It is a simple primitive variable.  But it is a *local* variable ... meaning that it is not shared across different calls to your recursive method.

Comment: The problem is that you do not explain what this actually supposed to do.  If you don't explain that (clearly!) then we can only guess ... and our suggested solutions will be guesses as well.   Note that we **do not** need the entire code.  What we need is a specification for (just) **this** code.

Comment: @StephenC This code is part of Sudoku Solver. The method `insertRandomValue()` realizes algorithm of deep search. The method search cells with the least quantity of possible variants in cells, insert one of variants in it and invoke method of accurate search of values `fillBoard()`. If the values in cells won't repeat in rows, columns and squares than recursion applies to find another cell with the least quantity of possible variants. If the values in cells will repeat than the method invoke method `restoreData()` which clears all cells filled after invoking of `insertRandomValue()`.

Comment: @Ensei - Please EDIT the question and include the explanation there.

Comment: @user16320675 There is just a part of whole code so you can not see changing data in the board. But they are so there is no risk endless cycle.

Comment: @user16320675 Besides, the variable v as global is not applicable in this case because it should be different for all recursions but global variable will make it similar